# PHP and mysql, SELECT query return null

Tags: php, mysql, database

this is PHP code:

```
<?php
// header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$d=$_GET["userid"];

 $servername = "*******";
 $username = "***";
 $password = "****";
 $dbname = "*****";
 $arr = array();

  $My_Connection = mysql_connect ( $servername, $username , $password ) ;
     if ( ! $My_Connection )
       {
           die( ' Could not connect : ' . mysql_error( ) ) ;
       }
    //pick data base
    mysql_select_db ( $dbname, $My_Connection );

    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$My_Connection);

         $sql_tempcreate="CREATE TABLE tmp(id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,DID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)";
         if(mysql_query($sql_tempcreate,$My_Connection))
         {
            $sql_convert="ALTER TABLE tmp CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8";
            mysql_query($sql_convert);

           $sql_inserttotemp="INSERT INTO tmp (DID) SELECT DID FROM user WHERE 1 Order By HIGHSCORE DESC";
                if(mysql_query($sql_inserttotemp,$My_Connection))

                {
                 //***************************************** from here problem start
                    $sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE DID =".$d."";//    |
                    $r=mysql_query($sql_rank,$My_Connection);             //    |
                                                                          //    |
                    $rank= $r;                                            //    V
                }//******************************************************** to here

         }
         else
         {
            $rank= array("ERROR","ERROR");
         }
            $output = json_encode(array('top' => $arr,'rank' =>$rank));
            echo ($output);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "there is an error :(";
    }
    mysql_query("DROP TABLE tmp",$My_Connection);
mysql_close($My_Connection); 

?>
```

**table tmp create successfully , data insert to tmp table successfully but "select query" return me null!**
actually **$r is null**
i try (LIKE & =)but same result

what is wrong with this query?

**EDIT:**

i even change the query to:

```
$sql_rank="SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE DID=352136069213581"
```

and not working again :(

tanks

**EDIT:
correct answer:**

tanks to **gaurav kumar** this is correct code :D

```
$sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE DID LIKE ".$d."";
$res=mysql_query($sql_rank,$My_Connection);
$r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$rank= $r;
```

Comment: Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`.

Comment: Have you checked `$d`?

Comment: $d is correct

sorry you mean it can't be with mysql_?!

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated

Comment: first use mysql_fetch_assoc( $rank, $My_Connection); then debug using print_r(); then check your output.

Comment: i even change the query to:

    $sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE DID=352136069213581"

**and not working again :(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tanks to **gaurav kumar** 
this is correct code :D

```
$sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE DID LIKE ".$d."";
$res=mysql_query($sql_rank,$My_Connection);
$r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$rank= $r;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$d` may be a string.So you need to enclose them in quotes (single or doubble)
Also trim spaces from `$d`

```
$d=trim($_GET["userid"]);
$sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE DID ='".$d."'";
```

Also try using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` because [mysql_* functions are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: i try this before but same result.

i have another SELECT QUERY in this PHP file and that work

Answer (score 1):

```
$d=trim($_GET["userid"]);
$sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE ID ='".$d."'";
```

Your Code was like this  : `$d=$_GET["userid"];`

```
$sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE DID ='".$d."'";
```

Not DID use ID

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $sql_rank="SELECT * FROM `tmp` WHERE DID =".$d."";
 $r=mysql_query($sql_rank,$My_Connection);
 $rank = mysql_fetch_row($r);
```

This will give you array of rows so you can fetch like `echo $rank[0];`

Comment: no this query give me id of that user

this code work correctly on my server and my app work correctly.

so answer is correct :D